# Incorrect parent element lxml

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am implementing a web scraping program in Python.

Consider my following HTML snippet.

```html
<div>
  <b> 
    <i>
      HelloWorld
   </i>
   HiThere
  </b>
</div>
```

If I wish to use lxml to extract my bold or italicized texts only, I use the following command

```
tree = etree.fromstring(myhtmlstr, htmlparser)
opp1 = tree.xpath(".//text()[ancestor::b or ancestor::i or ancestor::strong]")
```

This gives me the correct result, i.e. the result of my opp1 is :

> ['HelloWorld', 'HiThere']

So far, everything is perfect. However, the real problem arises if I try to query the parents of the tags. As expected, the output of `opp1[0].getparent().tag` and `opp1[0].getparent().getparent().tag` are `i` and `b`.

The real problem is however in the second tag. Ideally, the parent of `opp[1]` should be the `b` tag. However, the output of `opp1[1].getparent().tag` and `opp1[1].getparent().getparent().tag` are `i` and `b` again.

You can verify the same in the following code:

```
from lxml import etree
htmlstr = """<div><b><i>HelloWorld</i>HiThere</b></div>"""
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.fromstring(htmlstr, htmlparser)
opp1 = tree.xpath(".//text()[ancestor::b or ancestor::i or ancestor::strong]")
print(opp1)
print(opp1[0].getparent(), opp1[0].getparent().getparent())
print(opp1[1].getparent(), opp1[1].getparent().getparent())
```

Can someone point out why this is the case? What can I do to correct it? I plan to use only lxml for my program, and do not want any solution that uses bs4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to stem from LXML's (and ElementTree's) data model, where an element is roughly "tag, attributes, text, children, tail"; the DOM data model has actual nodes for text too.

If you change your program to do

```
for x in tree.xpath(".//text()[ancestor::b or ancestor::i or ancestor::strong]"):
    print(x, x.getparent(), "text?", x.is_text, "tail?", x.is_tail)
```

it will print

```
HelloWorld <Element i at 0x10aa0ccd0> text? True tail? False
HiThere <Element i at 0x10aa0ccd0> text? False tail? True
```

i.e. `"HiThere"` is the tail of the i element, since that's the way the Etree data model represents intermingled text and tags.

The takeaway here (which should probably work for your use case) is to consider `.getparent().getparent()` as the effective parent of a text result that has `is_tail=True`.

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense. Thanks for the quick answer!